# My husband has a beard in his passport photo, can he shave it off and still be able to board the ship?

Tags: passports

My husband has a beard on his photo passport photo but he wants to shave it before we go on our cruise, will this be a problem for him when boarding the ship?

Comment: Have you asked the cruise line operator?